How did Miles Morales' actions relate to Peter Parker's vulnerability?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Feeling a sting of disappointment when the Spider-People questioned his ability to
deactivate the Super Collider, Miles Morales chose to retreat. He slipped into invisibility,
distancing himself from the scene and found solace on the terrace.  A moment later,
Peter Parker joined him:

Miles Morales: I'm not like you guys.
Peter Parker: You mean the robot or the pig? Yeah, I mean, this is new
to me. I don't  know what I'm doing, all right? Congratulations, you
revealed me.

It suggests Miles Morales has unintentionally exposed Peter Parker's vulnerability
or lack of confidence.
How did Miles Morales' actions relate to Peter Parker's vulnerability?

"Miles Morales has unintentionally exposed Peter Parker's vulnerability or lack of confidence." - Yup. That.

@Valorum Can you post that as an answer?
